# Выдрать [язык]!

Tags: предложение, удаление-метки

На сайте присутствует две бессмысленных метки:

- [язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)
- [языки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Они используются в 60 вопросах и могут означать следующее:

- в вопросе используется язык программирования;
- в вопросе обсуждается язык программирования;
- в вопросе предлагается создать язык программирования;
- вопросе обсуждаются свойства языков програмирования;
- вопрос касается стандартов языка программирования;
- вопрос про проблемы локализации на естественный язык;
- вопрос про выбор языка програмирования;
- вопрос про кодировки;
- и так далее.

Предлагаю уничтожить метки.

Comment: Предлагаю туда же слить метку [любой язык]

Comment: @KromStern "Любой-язык" — это внеязыковые задачи. Аналог метки "language-agnostic" на большом СО. Это нормальная метка.

Comment: А что обозначает слово language в метке "language-agnostic", какую область?

Comment: @KromStern Обозначает отсутствие языка.

Comment: Отсутствие какого языка, программирования, разговорного, заливного?

Comment: Сорри, неясно выразился. Предлагаю все три метки слить в одну и назвать [язык-программирования]

Comment: @KromStern "Любой-язык" подразумевает, что описываемая проблема существует и может быть решена на многих языках, а не привязана к какому-то конкретному: алгоритмы, паттерны, аппаратная реализация, общие концепции. "Язык-программирования" будет подразумевать, что обсуждается какой-то язык программирования или его создание, что совсем другое. А "язык" и "языки" на данный момент вообще смысла не несут, так как каждый понимает их как хочет.

Answer (score 1):

Следует учесть, что русский SO включает в себя тематику не только английского SO, но и Programmers, например. Метка [язык] нужна, хотя бы до тех пор, пока не будут выпилены все вопросы относящиеся к языкам программирования вцелом. Мне кажется этого не произойдет. Так что предлагаю метки не трогать, а просто синонимизировать.

Comment: Эти метки очень редко используются для обсуждения межъязыковых вопросов, в лучшем случае встречаются бессмысленные вопросы типа "посоветуйте какой-нить язык программирования". Если оставлять, то надо основательно почистить.

Comment: С чисткой согласен, но беглым взглядом много тем где эти метки уместны.

Comment: Язык программирования надо называть языком программирования - а не просто "языком".